# Isapi Rewrite - preserving HTTPS in redirects behind load balancer

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, https, isapi-rewrite, load-balancing

I'm running a site which has 2 separate sub-domains - one for HTTP and another for HTTPS.

- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://secure.example.com`

`http://secure.example.com` does not exist and will not resolve.

The problem is that the site is running behind a load balancer which handles all SSL. Communication between the load balancer and the web servers in always HTTP.

So, when using Isapi Rewrite 3 (a mod_rewrite clone for IIS) to implement some redirects I'm running into a problem.

As far as Isapi Rewrite is concerned HTTPS is turned off - so redirects on `secure.example.com` are failing.

Say I have a rule which says:

```
RewriteRule ^/example/$ /test/ [R=301,L]
```

If I make a request for **`https://secure.example.com/example/`** I would like to end up on **`https://secure.example.com/test/`** but, because Isapi Rewrite sees HTTPS as OFF, I end up on  **`http://secure.example.com/test/`**.

Is there any way I can force redirects to be to HTTPS if the domain is `secure.example.com`?

Something along the lines of this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} secure.example.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://secure.example.com/$1
```

Except that doesn't work - it immediately forces an explicit redirect, whereas I want to continue processing other `RewriteRules`.

Thanks,

Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about smth like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/example/$ https://secure.mydomain.com/test/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks man - that does indeed work! I was hoping there was a way to run that domain check a single time, rather than before each rule - otherwise my .htaccess file is going to become quite bloated! Maybe that's hoping for too much...

Comment: If you put these rules into .htaccess in the root of secure.example.com, you can omit the host check at all.

Comment: I hear you - unfortunately I'm currently restricted to using the same .htaccess file on the secure and www domains. 

Marking this as the answer - thanks for the help!