# Sitecore - Enable HTTPS only on Content Authoring

Tags: ssl, sitecore, sitecore8

We need to enable the HTTPS for sitecore cms content authoring only.

I had a look at marketplace and couldn't find just for above purpose. Could someone please help how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to ensure that your content authoring environment (and the site as viewed on that environment) uses HTTPS you could set up an IIS rewrite rule to redirect to the HTTPS version of the URL.

The link mentioned in [Jason Horne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4531602/jason-horne)'s answer relates more to securing front-end pages than the Sitecore back end itself.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the urls from http to https though might be simple initially, as the requirement grows there will be lot of rules and conditions that creep up. Try to access the Content Authoring behind a load balancer. Encrypting whole page is processor oriented. So, employing a load balancer will help take the encryption from your content authoring server. This is something we did so many times in our Prod environments.

Care should be taken while using this option as we shouldn't generate absolute urls from application. We can use relative urls from root of the site though.

[Isapi Rewrite - preserving HTTPS in redirects behind load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130445/isapi-rewrite-preserving-https-in-redirects-behind-load-balancer?rq=1)

[My Loadbalancer holds ssl certificate so all requests to my site are http. How can I deal with situations where I need to redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322349/my-loadbalancer-holds-ssl-certificate-so-all-requests-to-my-site-are-http-how-c)